# Syntax Error in MySQL Script for user table

Tags: mysql, sql

Seems like every now and then I am having my troubles with MySQL. Can you help me with finding the error in this script? Thank you very much. I can't see it unfortunately.

```
Create table `User` (
id int not null,
lastname VARCHAR(50) not null,
firstname VARCHAR (50) not null,
email VARCHAR(100) not null,
password VARCHAR not null,
registered TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
active bit not null
constraint pk_UserId Primary Key(`id`)
);
```

Comment: I think you can see it

Comment: @Strawberry, thanks for the downvote. Appreciated

Comment: Not my dv, but happy to oblige

Comment: sorry somehow things just didn't work with the system. Idk what the problem was, even if I added the comma myself, it just didn't take it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Create table `User` (
    id int (11) not null,
    lastname VARCHAR(50) not null,
    firstname VARCHAR (50) not null,
    email VARCHAR(100) not null,
    password VARCHAR (50) not null,
    registered TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    active bit not null,
    constraint pk_UserId Primary Key(`id`)
);
```

You need to type length for ID and password

Also, comma `,` is missing in `active bit` line

Comment: Thanks. It works now.

Comment: Id doesn't need a length

Comment: @sevku: you can mark this as accepted answer

Comment: @Strawberry: ok noted but its better that we can set length so it will be manageable as per my opinion.

Comment: I am still trying to figure out why yours works but it doesn't when I add a comma. I start to feel stupid here

Comment: In what sense would it 'be manageable'

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite it please check

```
Create table `User2` (
id int not null,
lastname VARCHAR(50) not null,
firstname VARCHAR (50) not null,
email VARCHAR(100) not null,
password VARCHAR(100) not null,
registered TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
active bit not null,
constraint pk_UserId Primary Key(`id`)
);
```

Comment: Somehow it works. But am I right that you only added a comma?

Comment: right comma and length of your password @sevku

Answer (score 0):

Alright 
So you're using varchar and you have not defined the length.
Just like
    ***"password VARCHAR(100)"***
Define length for every varchar data type.

Comment: True but not the only error as others said a half hour prior-what additional info does this provide?